# MultipleObjectsReturned Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to display a page that shows all the bookings in a Booking model on a page.

views.py

```
def bookings(request):
    booking_list = get_object_or_404(Booking.objects.filter().order_by("-day"))
    return render(request, 'roombooker/base.html', {'booking_list': booking_list})
```

models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    day = models.DateField(u'Booking Day',help_text=u'Day of Booking')
    start_time = models.TimeField(u'Start Time', help_text=u'Start Time')
    end_time = models.TimeField(u'End Time', help_text=u'End Time')
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey('Room', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^bookings/',views.bookings, name='bookings'),
]
```

There are currently 10 dummy entries in the database that I put in.

When I try to go to the bookings page however I get:

> MultipleObjectsReturned at /bookings/
> get() returned more than one Booking -- it returned 10!

Which is what I want, I wanted 10 Booking objects. The idea was to pass it to the html for rendering.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Use `get_list_or_404` instead of `get_object_or_404`, the latter will call `.get()` and that triggers the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the name [**`get_object_or_404`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) suggests, this is used to retrieve a *single* element. Behind the curtains, it calls `.get()` on the queryset, and in case there is no element, it raises an exception, or a specified by the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

> Calls `get()` on a given model manager, but it raises `Http404` instead of the model's `DoesNotExist` exception.

`get_object_or_404` however has a slibing that returns a collection of elements: [**`get_list_or_404`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404). The difference is that here it raises an exception if the set is empty, and we obtain a collection of elements. Or like specified by the documentation:

> Returns the result of `filter()` on a given model manager cast to a list, raising `Http404` if the resulting list is empty.

So we can implement the view as:

```
def bookings(request):
    booking_list = get_list_or_404(Booking.objects.filter().order_by("-day"))
    return render(request, 'roombooker/base.html', {'booking_list': booking_list})
```

> **Note**: if you do not want to `.filter()` the queryset on anything, it is advisable to use `.all()` instead.

In case you do not want to materialize the queryset into a list, we can implement the check ourselves with:

```
from django.http import Http404

def bookings(request):
    booking_list = Booking.objects.all().order_by("-day")
    if not book_list:
        raise Http404('No bookings found')
    return render(request, 'roombooker/base.html', {'booking_list': booking_list})
```

Comment: This solved the problem exactly, I need to do more research before posting. Thank you